# why do objects get the same result by assigning the same arraylist with a different state in each of them

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, methods, attributes

Problem manipulating arraylist in methods from objects in Java OOP, the methods take the last state
of the arraylist ignoring that i want one object to have some elements of the array and other object to have the other elements.

As you can see in the first sample code I have two objects and I want to give them by the method two different contents of the same arraylist because it was defined in my method that is on the second sample code, but when I remove one object from the array and use the method in the second object with the intention to give it the elements of the arraylist without the previous first element "folclore", both results are the same, both objects take the last state of the arraylist with the element "folclore" out,(you can see in the results), so it's possible to solve it?

First sample code:

```
ArrayList<Album> albuns = new ArrayList<Album>();
Collections.addAll(albuns, folclore, sedimentar,angry,sick,hungry,fever,fast,slow,happy,sad);
lilnas.setAlbuns(albuns);
albuns.remove(0);
filipe.setAlbuns(albuns);
```

Second sample code(method):

```
public void setAlbuns(ArrayList<Album> albuns){
   this.albuns = albuns;
}
```

Results:

Filipe albums:

```
Sedimentar - 07/04/2023 - gravado - South Park
Angry - 07/07/2020 - Ao vivo - Quicks
Sick - 30/11/2015 - gravado - Batman
Hungry - 05/12/2019 - gravado - Flash
Fever - 05/03/2015 - gravado - Batman
Fast - 10/03/2020 - Ao vivo - Quicks
Slow - 07/07/2010 - gravado - North park
Happy - 04/09/2010 - gravado - North Park
Sad - 11/06/2019 - gravado - Flash
```

Lilnas albums:

```
Sedimentar - 07/04/2023 - gravado - South Park
Angry - 07/07/2020 - Ao vivo - Quicks
Sick - 30/11/2015 - gravado - Batman
Hungry - 05/12/2019 - gravado - Flash
Fever - 05/03/2015 - gravado - Batman
Fast - 10/03/2020 - Ao vivo - Quicks
Slow - 07/07/2010 - gravado - North park
Happy - 04/09/2010 - gravado - North Park
Sad - 11/06/2019 - gravado - Flash
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: Oh sorry, solved!

Comment: `lianas` and `Felipe` both contain a reference to the *same* `ArrayList`, so naturally it has the same contents. You'll need to take a copy of the `ArrayList` in `setAlbums` to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: Your title already answers your own question: because you're assigning the same array list.